Where should my C wire be connected at the furnace?
I have had a Google Nest for a while now and I realized that it never turns off and I connected the C wire during installation but realized today it’s not actually connected into anything. The cables are spliced and I need help knowing which bundle I should attach the Blue C wire to. My AC keeps freezing and I’m in Texas so this would be a huge help and save me a lot of money. Thanks!



Kindly define "C wire".

In the left-hand end of the lower partition there's a transformer. If you follow the wires from the terminals, you should find that two of of them connect back to the AC mains power. Those are the "high voltage" or "primary" terminals. The other two terminals are the "low voltage" or "secondary" terminals. One of these will connect to the R wire of the thermostat. The other one is where the C connection can be made.
The terminal on the right, nearest the camera, appears to have a green wire and a red wire crimped into it with the green wire attached to the equipment chassis. I think this is the one you're looking for, but do examine the connections yourself to be sure. Measuring AC volts with a meter is a good idea too; you should find something around 24-27 volts between R and the suspected C.
